# Chain Responsibility Pattern to filtering messages

Tags: python, python-2.x, design-patterns

Is this a good implementation of a Chain Responsibility Pattern? This code attempts to filter a message received (for instance, in a chat application).

```
import urlmarker
import re

bad_words = []
with open("bad-words.txt") as file:
    for entry in file:
        entry = entry.strip()
        bad_words.append(entry)


class Message(object):

    def __init__(self, content):
        self.content = content.split()
        self.can_broadcast = True
        self.construct_word()

    def construct_word(self):
        self.content = ' '.join(self.content)

class Filter():

    def __init__(self, successor = None):
        self.successor = successor

    def has_successor(self):
        if self.successor is not None:
            return True
        return False

    def filter_message(self, message):
        if self.has_successor():
            self.successor.filter_message(message)

class Slang_Filter(Filter):

    def filter_message(self, message):
        has_bad_words = False

        for word in message.content:
                for bad_word in bad_words:
                    if bad_word == word.lower():
                        has_bad_words = True
                        break

        if has_bad_words == False:
            if self.has_successor():
                self.successor.filter_message(message)
        else:
            message.can_broadcast = False

class Website_Filter(Filter):

    def filter_message(self, message):
        has_websites = False

        if re.findall(urlmarker.URL_REGEX, message.content) is None:
            if self.has_successor():
                self.successor.filter_message(message)
        else:
            message.can_broadcast = False



def main():
    new_message = Message("This is full of fucking shit www.google.com")
    slang_filter = Slang_Filter()
    website_filter = Website_Filter(slang_filter)
    website_filter.filter_message(new_message)
    print new_message.can_broadcast

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Do you really think you need the chain of responsibility pattern here? The point of chain of responsibility is creating hierarchies. If you have website filter isn't what you need is just `all(predicate(message) for predicate in predicates)`. Also use comprehensions instead of creating empty lists and then appending to them in for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Chain of Responsibility

- Rather than building the chain on instantiation, make the creation of the chain a function.
  This can allow you to chain the creation, which is easier to read and nicer to look at.
- I'd also make the chain return, rather than mutate a foreign object.
  This removes side effects, which lead to hard to understand code, and potential bugs.
- `has_successor` is a poor function, it's simpler to read and understand using `if self._next is not None`, rather than using that abstraction.
  And so I'd remove it, I'd favour writing out the non-function way anyway.

And so I'd come to:

```
class Filter(object):
    _next = None
    def add_filter(self, next_filter):
        self._next = next_filter
        return next_filter

    def filter_message(self, message):
        if self._next is None:
            return True
        return self._next.filter_message(message)

class SlangFilter(Filter):
    def filter_message(self, message):
        for word in message.content:
            for bad_word in bad_words:
                if bad_word == word.lower():
                    return False

        if self._next is None:
            return True
        return self._next.filter_message(message)

class Website_Filter(Filter):
    def filter_message(self, message):
        if re.findall(urlmarker.URL_REGEX, message.content) is not None:
            return False

        if self._next is None:
            return True
        return self._next.filter_message(message)
```

This then lets you create the chain as:

```
def main():
    new_message = Message("This is full of fucking shit www.google.com")
    filter = WebsiteFilter()
        .add_filter(SlangFilter())
    print filter.filter_message(new_message)
```

---

Going forward, you'd want to change your classes in a couple of other ways too.

- Rather than relying on a global bad words variable, `SlangFilter` should be passed these words on instantiation.
- Rather than manually re-creating `in`, you can use it to reduce code complexity, and for a performance boost, if you were to change the list of words to a `set`.
- Your code shouldn't rely on an unneeded model, as a string is good enough for this.

And so I'd use:

```
import urlmarker
import re


class Filter(object):
    _next = None
    def add_filter(self, next_filter):
        self._next = next_filter
        return next_filter

    def filter_message(self, message):
        if self._next is None:
            return True
        return self._next.filter_message(message)


class SlangFilter(Filter):
    def __init__(self, bad_words):
        self._bad_words = {word.lower() for word in bad_words}
    
    def filter_message(self, message):
        for word in message.lower().split():
            if word in self._bad_words:
                return False

        if self._next is None:
            return True
        return self._next.filter_message(message)


class Website_Filter(Filter):
    def filter_message(self, message):
        if re.findall(urlmarker.URL_REGEX, message) is not None:
            return False

        if self._next is None:
            return True
        return self._next.filter_message(message)


def main():
    with open("bad-words.txt") as file:
        bad_words = [word.strip() for word in file]
    
    message = "This is full of fucking shit www.google.com"
    filter = WebsiteFilter()
        .add_filter(SlangFilter(bad_words))
    print filter.filter_message(message)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I found a _bug_ in my code that was also passed on to your code:
`if re.findall(urlmarker.URL_REGEX, message) is not None:`
should be:
`if not re.findall(urlmarker.URL_REGEX, message):`
Or else, it will always return `not None`

Comment: @TomasCarvalho If you found a bug post it as an answer, and you should get upvotes, :)

Comment: I think that your implementation (or is it me that is failing to implement it correctly...) is wrong. When you add `SlangFilter`, you are returning it. As such, when we call the method `filter.filter_message(message)` we are only using `SlangFilter`, as it starts with `SlangFilter` and its `_successor` is None. As such, `WebFilter` is never used. I'm trying to correct this bug, but it's tricky... 
I hope I'm making myself clear :)

Comment: @TomasCarvalho There's no point in calling the other functions after the first `return False`, and so I returned early

Comment: The problem is with this code or the way that it's used when a filter is created:
`def add_filter(self, next_filter):
        self._next = next_filter
        return next_filter
`
Even if the message is clean (for instance, "Hello World"), only one filter will be used on it...

Comment: @TomasCarvalho That's wrong, it only calls one if it's false, check out short-circuit evaluation. There's no need to go into the other functions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58079/discussion-between-tomascarvalho-and-peilonrayz).

Answer (score 1):

After thoroughly analysing my code and @Peilonrayz answer, I came to the conclusion that there is a bug in the WebsiteFilter class. The following code will always return False:

```
if re.findall(urlmarker.URL_REGEX, message) is not None:
    return False
```

The problem is that `re.findall` will return a list, empty or not, and as such it will never be `None`. It should be changed to:

```
if not re.findall(urlmarker.URL_REGEX, message):
    return False
```

Other bug that I found is that in @Peilonrayz answer

```
filter = WebsiteFilter()
        .add_filter(SlangFilter(bad_words))
```

will make the filter be initialised with SlangFilter, instead of being initialised with WebsiteFilter, or as @Peilonrayz put it: "we're using the leaf, rather than the root".

The correct way to initialise a filter would be:

```
filter = WebsiteFilter()
filter.add_filter(SlangFilter())
```

**Conclusion** 
@Peilonrayz answer is still the correct answer. However, if you are seeing this, make sure you correct the above bugs so the code will work as it's supposed to.